# How to get range of a particular value in a list of list in Python?

Tags: python

For example I have a list

```
my_list=[['E', '101_CHEK1'],
['E', '101_CHEK1'],
['E', '101_CHEK1'],
['B', '101_CHEK1'],
['B', '101_CHEK1'],
['E', '101_CHEK1'],
['E', '101_CHEK1'],
['E', '101_CHEK1'],
['B', '101_CHEK1'],
['E', '101_CHEK1']]
```

How do I get range of the first element in the list i.e E:[0-2],
B:[3-4],E:[5-7] .... So far what I came up with is as follows:

```
d={}
a=0
for j,i in enumerate(my_list):
  a+=1
  if i[0] not in d:
    d[i[0]]=[j]
  else:
    d[i[0]].append(j)
```

`{'B': [3, 4, 8], 'E': [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9]}`

Is there any particular approach that I should follow? The final O/P should be
 `E:[0-2],B:[3-4],E:[5-7]`

Comment: You won't be able to get the results you expect as a dictionary because you have repeating keys.  Is there an alternative output or type it could be?

Answer (score 3):

Explanation in comments

```
my_list=[['E', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['E', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['E', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['B', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['B', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['E', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['E', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['E', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['B', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1'],['E', '101_CHEMBL1236539_CHEK1']]

from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)
# create a simple dictionary with element position for each elemets
for i,ele in enumerate(my_list):
    dic[ele[0]] = dic[ele[0]]+[i]

# next problem: get consecutive groups [1,2,4,5,6] ==> (1,2),(4,6)
# You can also use more_iterrools.consecutive_groups here.
# Implementation taken from https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#consecutive_groups

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def get_consecutive_groups(iterables):
    groups = []
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(iterables), key=lambda x: x[0] - x[1]):
        g = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))
        groups.append((g[0],g[-1]))
    return (groups)

#create a new dictionary where we have the groupings stored
new_dic = {}
for key in dic.keys():
    new_dic[key] = get_consecutive_groups(dic[key])
print(new_dic)
```

Output:

```
{'E': [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9, 9)], 'B': [(3, 4), (8, 8)]}
```

Comment: This is great. Just a question, I am getting an error as follows when I run the code:
`NameError: name 'itemgetter' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always make it shorter:

```
dict_example = {'B': [x for x in range(len(my_list)) if my_list[x][0] == 'B'], 'E': [x for x in range(len(my_list)) if my_list[x][0] == 'E']}
print(dict_example)
```

Output:

```
{'B': [3, 4, 8], 'E': [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9]}
```